# How does `in` operator work with maps?

Tags: elixir

How does `in` operator work with maps?

```
iex(12)> "a" in %{"a" => "b"}
false
iex(13)> "b" in %{"a" => "b"}
false
iex(14)> {"a", "b"} in %{"a" => "b"}
true
iex(15)> {"a", "a"} in %{"a" => "b"}
false
```

If it returns true only for tuple representing key and value, why does it not raise error in the first two calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [in/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Kernel.html#in/2) it states:

> This operator (which is a macro) simply translates to a call to Enum.member?/2.

[Enum.member?/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Enum.html#member?/2) works on any Enumberable.

[The implementation of `member?/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/33e3e2e772dbbfd4616ca5b137fc009ec1ce1b01/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L2805) required for the Enumerable protocol for a map:

```
  def member?(map, {key, value}) do
    {:ok, match?({:ok, ^value}, :maps.find(key, map))}
  end

  def member?(_map, _other) do
    {:ok, false}
  end
```

You can see other instances of maps being transformed to tuples for the Enumerable protocol with the following code:

```
iex(4)> Enum.map(%{"a" => "b", 1 => 2}, & &1)
[{1, 2}, {"a", "b"}]
```

Comment: Kinda hard to understand, but answers the question. Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend also taking a look at the protocols page from the getting started guide. http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html